# Is there a way to trigger a script (ksh) as non-root user on logon, other than adding it to .profile?

Tags: linux, ksh

Since I dont have `root access`, I cannot add the script to `.profile`.

I tried to use `crontab` to make it run every 10 secs. Even that is not allowed, since I am not root.

Comment: No idea about ksh or linux. On freebsd with csh the startup script per user is in users home directory and named ".cshrc". So my first guess would be that you need some ".kshrc" startup script in your home folder.

Comment: You should own the .profile in your home directory, and be able to add your script to it.  Try `ls -l $HOME/.profile`

Answer (score 0):

In executing the program in `cron` there is no need of root permission. Because 
each and every user should have the separate `cron` entry. So you can do that using cron.

Answer (score 0):

Your ~/.profile should be under your control, as should your own crontab.  That is, unless your sysadmin has gone out of her way to prevent users from manipulating these.  In which case, you will just need to talk to them.

If your ~/.profile is not loading you may want to try ~/.kshrc if you are using Korn Shell as your user's shell.  Or if it's bash you can use ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile (this is most common on linux).